# Convert regex captured lowercase group to uppercase

Tags: html, regex, uppercase, lowercase, capture-group

I would like to insert a set of links in a text. The link is partly composed of a regex pattern. That works. But the captured group, which I have to use, consists of uppercase letters. But the link requires small letters.

```
text=re.sub
(r'firstpart(FirstCapturedGrp)(SecondCapturedGrp)', 
r'<a href="www.bla.com/\1/\2', 'str')
```

Second Captured group Uppercase in the source, but needs to be lowercase. Is there a way to convert it?